# Mongoose: disable empty query returning a document

Tags: node.js, mongoose

When using Mongoose (with bluebird in my case, but using callbacks to illustrate), the following codes all return a document from the collection:

```
model.findOne({}, function(err, document) {
    //returns a document
})
model.findOne(null, function(err, document) {
    //returns a document
})
model.findOne([], function(err, document) {
    //returns a document
})
```

I would like to know if and how I can disable this kind of behaviour, as it is becoming a liability to my code where I infer queries from data a user feeds into the system. Especially the null query returning a valid document worries me.

As of right now I check the input for being an non-empty, non-array, non-null object, but it's becoming a bit cumbersome at scale.

What would be the best way to exclude this behaviour?

Comment: You shouldn't trust user in first place. Since findOne takes an object as first param you should check at least that it is an object. You can't expect correct result if you passing in incorrect data.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the best way to go about it, but right now I've settled on using a pre-hook on the model itself which checks for the _conditions property of the 'this' object (which I inferred from printing seems to hold the query object) to not be empty.

Inserting a self-defined object in the next functionality causes the Promise to reject in which the query was originally called from.

( _ is the underscore package)

```
//model.js
//model is a mongoose.Schema type in the following code

model.pre('findOne', function(next) {
  var self = this

  if (_.isEmpty(self._conditions)) {
    next(mainErrors.malformedRequest)
  } else {
    next()
  }
})
```